# Rigorous definition of a charge

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

A charge usually is defined as a sigma-additive set function which can't take both values $+\infty$ and $-\infty$. 
However one must require absolute convergence of the series in the RHS of 
$$
\nu \left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\nu(A_i)
$$
in order to have a well-defined set function. Where can I find a really rigorous definition?

Comment: In books on measure theory. In mathematics, those things are often called "signed measures".

Comment: [The Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_measure) should be rigorous enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\nu(\bigcup A_i)$ is finite, then the right hand side must be independent of the rearrangement of terms. Then, since every rearrangement of the terms has $\sum\nu(A_i)<\infty$, it follows from Riemann's rearrangement theorem that $\sum|\nu(A_i)|<\infty$.

We do not require the convergence of the series, indeed you may have terms within the summation which take values $\nu(A_i)=\pm\infty$. We use the convention that if any one term in the series takes value $\pm\infty$, then the series (and hence measure of the union) takes value $\pm\infty$.

The restriction we make is that precisely one of the following must always hold: $\nu(A)<+\infty$ for all $A\in\Sigma$, or $\nu(A)>-\infty$ for all $A\in\Sigma$. This avoids situations whereby the series is undefined.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. We really don't need to impose the absolute convergence limitation.